# How should I define a NOT operator which supports both NOT and AND NOT in LARK

Tags: python, lark-parser

This is how my current code looks like, it only supports `a AND NOT b`. Is there a way to make it also return the same tree for `a NOT b`? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
from lark import Lark


grammar = r'''
    start: or_test

    ?or_test: and_test ("OR" and_test)*
    ?and_test: not_test ("AND" not_test)*
    ?not_test: "NOT" not_test -> not
             | atom
    
    atom: WORD -> term
         | "(" or_test ")"

    WORD: /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/
    
    %import common.WS_INLINE
    %ignore WS_INLINE
'''

parser = Lark(grammar)

s = 'NOT a AND b AND NOT c'
tree = parser.parse(s)
print(tree.pretty())
```

***output***

```
start
  and_test
    not
      term  a
    term    b
    not
      term  c
```

Comment: "it only supports a AND NOT b" I don't understand; the rule looks right to me, and the output also looks right to me. What were you expecting instead?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I want `a NOT b` also returns the same result at the same time.

Comment: That... doesn't make any sense. `NOT` is a unary operator, not a binary one.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I know... but unfortunately it's the grammar of our queries. what I really need is the support of `NOT a` and `a NOT b`, `a NOT AND b` is actually optional since people mostly use the first 2 cases.

Comment: `NOT a` is totally normal, and should already be supported by your grammar. I assume `a NOT AND b` is supposed to mean the same thing as `a AND NOT b`? But what does `a NOT b` actually mean? The same thing again?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel right, `a NOT AND b` and `a NOT b` are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that should do what you asked:

```
from lark import Lark

grammar = r'''
    start: or_test

    ?or_test: and_test ("OR" and_test)*
    ?and_test: not_test ("AND" not_test | and_not)*
    and_not: "NOT" not_test -> not
    ?not_test: "NOT" not_test -> not
            | atom

    atom: WORD -> term
        | "(" or_test ")"

    WORD: /[a-zA-Z0-9]+/

    %import common.WS_INLINE
    %ignore WS_INLINE
'''

parser = Lark(grammar)

s = 'NOT a AND b AND NOT c NOT d'
tree = parser.parse(s)
print(tree.pretty())
```